# Access a PHP-object with dollar-sign as node name - Parse error: syntax error, (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, json, youtube-api, xampp

Before we get into this, I've found the exact issue i'm dealing with, however the solution does not fix my issue.

[Access a PHP-object with dollar-sign as node name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378807/access-a-php-object-with-dollar-sign-as-node-name)

Here is the relevant PHP code.

```
$user = 'officialtiesto';

$artist_json = file_get_contents('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' .  $user  . '?alt=json');
$artist_object = json_decode($artist_json, FALSE);

var_dump($artist_object->'yt$googlePlusUser');
```

I have also tried this:

```
var_dump($artist_object->{'yt$googlePlusUser'})
```

Both present me with the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''yt$googlePlusUser''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
>   C:\Users\astark\Desktop\charts\youtube.php on line 22

I read somewhere that having an out of date version of PHP can cause issues similar to this so i've included a link to a JSBin (http://jsbin.com/yahevoyo) with the specs of the XAMPP setup i'm running. Pretty stumped here on this one and not sure if its just the late night getting to me, or a larger problem. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no `yt$googlePlusUser`, it's `yt$googlePlusUserId`.
Then you've missed one level. Instead of

```
$artist_object->{'yt$googlePlusUserId'}
```

use

```
$artist_object->entry->{'yt$googlePlusUserId'}
```

And finally, as a bonus, to get the ID:

```
$artist_object->entry->{'yt$googlePlusUserId'}->{'$t'}
```

Alternatively as it's written in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4378856/1267140) to the question you referred to you could convert the JSON object to an array using `$artist = json_decode($artist_json, true)` and access the property as `$artist['entry']['yt$googlePlusUserId']['$t]`.

**Update:**
Regarding PHP version, etc. you seem to have 5.4.19 installed, I've tested the above on 5.4.0 and it works.

Comment: Seems I was a victim of late night coding again. Thank you very much!